# OLS standard errors vs GLS standard errors

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

### I currently have a dataset with y and x that seems to experience heteroskedasticity.

Are the results consistent/within expectations?

(The standard error for x from my GLS is even higher than that of the common OLS.)

Next I want to try using feasible GLS to estimate the regression equation.

```
regress y x [aw = 1/h]  #My code for WLS in Stata
```

Result:

[image]

Comparing with the common OLS y on x regression:

[image]

----------My Method-----------

According to my textbook, the steps of doing GLS:

Step 1: Regress y on x to obtain residuals u_hat

Step 2: Regress log(u_hat^2) on x to obtain fitted values g_hat

Step 3: Take exponential to obtain exp(g_hat), set this equal to h

Step 4: Run WLS (weighted least squares) using 1/h as weights.